# Hashmaps having multiple keys with multiple values

Tags: java, hashmap

Is it possible for me to have multiple keys and multiple values for my .ini file? if so how?

i know we can have single key with multiple values using list or multimaps but can i replicate the same concept for multiple keys
like this-keys-a,b,c
values-(for row 1)d,e,f and so on for multiple rows
what i actually want is this for my ini file

```
   key1||key2||key3
   value1||value2||value3
   value4||value5||value6
```

key1 maps to value1 and4 and so on

and all of this should be in one map

Comment: so you have a map for which key is "a","b","c" and value is "d","e","f".. something like that ?

Comment: can you add some example, please?

Comment: the values should be retrieved in the same order as are the keys....like key1 retrieves value1 and value4......ke2 retrieves value2 and value5 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re your edit, it looks like you want to retrieve by any of the keys. So all you really have here is a `String : List` map.

Just loop through that file, split each line on `||`, and add the first entry to the first key's list, the second entry to the second key's list, etc.

Very roughly, Java-like pseudocode:

```
Map<String, List> map = HashMap<String, List>();
String line;
String[] entries;
int index;
String[] keys;

//...open file...

// First line is keys
line = source.readLine();
if (line == null) {
    // File is empty
}
else {
    // Add the keys
    keys = new String[entries.size()];
    index = 0;
    for (String key : entries) {
         keys[index++] = key;
         map.put(key, new LinkedList());
    }

    // Process entries
    while ((line = source.readLine()) != null) {
        entries = line.split("\\|\\|");
        index = 0;
        for (String entry : entries) {
            if (index >= keys.length) {
                break;
            }
            map.get(keys[index++]).add(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

...or something like that.

---

**Original answer**, just for anyone finding this later who wants to go another way:

I can read your question two ways:

If you mean you want to store a `List` under several keys and use any one of them to retrieve it, you can do that:

```
map.put(key1, list);
map.put(key2, list);
map.put(key3, list);

// ...later
list = map.get(key1); // or key2, or key3
```

If you mean you want to retrieve using *all* of the keys but not the keys individually, then conceptually that's just one key. You could derive from any of the `Map` or `List` classes, add your own `equals` and `getHashCode` as appropriate to your definition of the "same" key, and use that:

```
map.put(specialMultiKey, list);

// ...later
list = map.get(specialMultiKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Common Collection's MultiKeyMap: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html

[EDIT: If you don't want to use it, you can write your own implementation of MuliKeyMap by extending Map and providing an implementation similar to what is given in MultiKeyMap.]